# EXTJS4 Gridpanel- How to focus/highlight a particular row?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am working on a GridPanel. I just want to focus a particular row based on the value it has(maximum value) How do I achieve this. I haven't found any method in the EXT4.1 documentation.

Comment: I take it that by 'focus' you don't mean 'select'. Correct?

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at `Ext.grid.View` for your methods. There's a `focusRow` method that can take a store record as an argument. Sounds exactly like what you're looking for. However, this won't apply any special CSS to the row; it will just scroll it into view. You can use `highlightItem` or `addRowCls` to change how the row looks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be controlled by the renderer property for each column.  Define a function for each type of renderer.  And then call that function in each column definition in your Ext.grid.Panel.  So in your case, apply the renderer to each column.  Perhaps change the background color or do something unique.  This will cover the conditional value question.  For row selection, take a look at this link.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/array-grid.html

```
function pctChange(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }
    return val;
}


    columns: [
        {
            text     : '% Change',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange'
        },
```